# $http success and failure comebacks, ng-repeat and accessing $scope

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to generate an html table of data.

Each generated row in the table has an input field that has ng-blur on it.

When ng-blur is activated I make an $http request and, upon success, it calls my success callback. This is all working.

Inside the success (and failure callback for that matter) callback I would like to be able to change the background color of the input that was just changed to a light green color for a few seconds to indicate that the box they just tabbed off of was updated (or red from my failure callback).

**How can I go about accessing and setting the appropriate style for a few seconds on the just changed element from inside the success (or failure) callbacks?**

I'm trying to make it work with ng-style but my problem is that I am having trouble accessing the $scope that has my data from inside the success (or failure) callbacks.

**UPDATE**

Here is my markup:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="psr in programStackRanks.data | filter:{ TeamProject: teamProject} | orderBy:sortPredicate">
    <td>{{psr.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{psr.Title}}</td>
    <td>{{psr.State}}</td>
    <td><input data-id="{{psr.Id}}" data-original-rank="{{psr.OriginalRank}}" type="number" min=0 value="{{psr.ProgramStackRank}}" ng-blur="updateProgramStackRank($event)" ng-style="ResultStyle"/></td>
    <td>{{psr.TeamProject}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Are you using a directive on the input element?

Comment: Without the code, I suppose you use isolate scope when having trouble accessing $scope?

Comment: I am using ng-blur (which is working fine) and trying to use ng-style but I cannot seem to access the current scope item to set its property to activate ng-style. The input I am using is the hijacked angualr one (input[type=number]).

Comment: I added the markup for the tr generation.

Comment: @Matty I am not using a custom directive (as can be seen in my updated post).

Comment: I see the problem but don't have elegant solution. Yet.

Comment: What about creating a directive that would bind to the onblur event of the element and make the $http call from the directive?

Comment: I was hoping to use the built in one if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily the prettiest solution, but you could do it something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-blur="updateProgramStackRank($event, psr.id)" ng-style="getResultStyle(psr.id)" />
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.styled_ids = []
$scope.getResultStyle = function(id) {
      if ($scope.styled_ids.indexOf(id) !== -1) 
          return {"background-color":"blue"}
}
$scope.updateProgramStackRank = function($event, id) {
   $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
      success(function(data) {
          $scope.styled_ids.push(id);

          $timeout(function() { 
              var index = $scope.styled_ids.indexOf(id);
              if (index > -1) {
                  $scope.styled_ids.splice(index, 1);
              }
          }, 1000);
      })
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8pk9/

I used $timeout in the fiddle instead of $http for convenience, but it shows the concept.

Comment: When I try adapting this the $scope inside my success method is not the same scope as where I declared the ids array.

Comment: So to fix this I moved my success callback into the initial function ($scope.updateProgramStackRank). Now trying to figure out why ng-style is not reflecting.

Comment: ng-style isn't calling my function for some reason even though I am pushing the id into the array.

Comment: I realized I needed to attach getResultStyle to the $scope.

Comment: But it still can't seem to keep track of the ids. It loses them for some reason. I'm even trying to stuff the array in a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing (thanks to dave who is getting the credit for pointing me in the right direction:

My updated tr looks like this

```
  <tr ng-repeat="psr in programStackRanks.data | filter:{ TeamProject: teamProject} | orderBy:sortPredicate">
    <td>{{psr.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{psr.Title}}</td>
    <td>{{psr.State}}</td>
    <td><input data-id="{{psr.Id}}" data-original-rank="{{psr.OriginalRank}}" type="number" min=0 value="{{psr.ProgramStackRank}}" ng-blur="updateProgramStackRank($event)" ng-style="getResultStyle({{psr.Id}})"/></td>
    <td>{{psr.TeamProject}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Notice I had to use the template syntax as psr.Id without the braces wasn't working).

and here is an excerpt from my js:

```
updateProgramStackRank =
            function ($event) {
                var id = $event.target.attributes["data-id"].value,
                    rank = $event.target.value,
                    originalRank = $event.target.attributes["data-original-rank"].value;

                if (rank === originalRank) {
                    //  Nothing changed
                    return;
                }

                psreService.updateProgramStackRank(id, rank).then(
                    function (response) {
                        var id = parseInt(response.config.data.id);
                        successIds.push(id);

                        $timeout(function () {
                            var index = successIds.indexOf(id);
                            if (index > -1) {
                                successIds.splice(index, 1);

                                var index2 = failureIds.indexOf(id);
                                if (index2 > -1) {
                                    failureIds.splice(index, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }, 3000);
                    },
                    function (reason) {
                        var id = parseInt(reason.config.data.id);
                        failureIds.push(id);
                    }
                );
            },
        getResultStyle =
            function (id) {
                //debugger;
                if (successIds.indexOf(id) > -1) {
                    return { "background-color": "green" };
                }
                if (failureIds.indexOf(id) > -1) {
                    return { "background-color": "red" };
                }
                return { "background-color": "white" };
            }, 
        successIds = [], 
        failureIds = [];
```

Without creating a custom directive and only using out of the box (which is what I wanted) I used a closure (successIds and failureIds) to maintain the list of ids. I was originally attaching them to the scope but when I push it was pushing to the child scope created by ng-repeat and not the original items.

I want to also point out that the original plan was for the $scope.successIds and $.scope.failureIds to add and remove the ids. When the $scope array changed the ng-style would be updated.

The reason it still works even though there is nothing watching the closured arrays is because everytime the $digest runs it re-evaluates the ng-style expression and the closured arrays are there alive and kicking.